# Is there a generic Event a AWS Lambda function can receive, and then determine which type of event is it?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis

I'm currently learning about AWS Lambda and how to trigger it from other services. I've managed to use SNS topic (with help of [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html)) to publish a json like:

```
{
    "name":"Bojack",
    "lastName":"Horseman",
    "job":"Horsin around"
}
```

and triggers the Lambda function:

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<SNSEvent, MyResponse> {

    public MyResponse handleRequest(SNSEvent request, Context context){

        String input = request.getRecords().get(0).getSNS().getMessage();
        MyRequest myRequest = new Gson().fromJson(input, MyRequest.class);

        context.getLogger().log(MyRequest.toString());

        // do some logic

        return null;
     }
}
```

It works great!

However, now I'm trying to figure out how to add a new service that can also trigger this function.
For example SQS, or kinesis. AFAIK these services send different json input to the lambda function, and I'm not sure about how to receive it since I'm currently using **SNSEvent**

Is there a way to receive a Generic Event and inside the handler determine which service was the one who send it? So that way I can parse it to that specific event and get the **message**

I've read about [AWS Lambda Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) but I'm not sure if that's the way to go. Also I didn't really understand it

Comment: You can use `InputStream` or `String` as  the request type and then figure out which kind of event is from the structure.

Comment: @yorodm I get an unable to parse exception when trying to receive a String. That's why I started using SNSEvent

Comment: You could write multiple handlers within the same Lambda function with different signatures.

Comment: @Mokz is this error from the lambda runtime or on the Java side

Comment: What I do is parse the event as compare to expectations regarding the know formats (SQS, SQS, API gateway and so on).

Answer (score 0):

AWS publishes many events in the `aws-lambda-java-events` library which includes generic events such as `APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent`. Those events essentially give you generic beans to handle the event JSON. Check out the project here: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/main/aws-lambda-java-events

Answer (score 0):

Event source mapping is basically what you do when you define a trigger, you connect a source to your lambda. Unfortunatedly every event type has its own format, so reading it as plain json or typed clases won't help in generalizing it. I was told event bridge can help here, haven't done anything with it yet.